# Como usar RNCryptor e Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, criptografia

Estive pesquisando formas de criptografar os dados de usuário de um aplicativo Android que utiliza Firebase. Neste [artigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38184219/how-to-use-rncryptor-and-firebase-togeather-swift-objective-c) é recomendado o RNCryptor, porém sem detalhes da implementação. Encontrei esta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38184219/how-to-use-rncryptor-and-firebase-togeather-swift-objective-c) sobre o uso para iOS. Como fazer o mesmo para Android?

(Também aceito sugestões de outras formas de criptografia, pois não tenho experiência com isso).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar usar a Base64 do próprio android.

import android.util.Base64;

private String CodificarBase64(String texto){
        return Base64.encodeToString(texto.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT).replaceAll("(\n|\r)", "");
    }

private String DecodificarBase64(String textoCod){
        return new String(Base64.decode(textoCod, Base64.DEFAULT));
    }